# Spark UDF error when input parameter is a value concatenated from two columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Following python code loads a `csv` file into `dataframe df` and sends a string value from single or multiple columns of `df` to `UDF` function `testFunction(...)`. The code works fine if I send a single column value. But if I send a value `df.address + " " + df.city` from two columns of df, I get the following error:

**Question**: What I may be doing wrong, and how can we fix the issue? All the columns in `df` are   NOT NULL so null or empty string should not be an I issue. For example if I send single column value df.address, that value has blank spaces (e.g. 123 Main Street). So, why the error when two columns' concatenated values are sent to UDF?

**Error**:

> PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper''

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.read.csv(".......dfs.core.windows.net/myDataFile.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true")

def testFunction(value):
  mystr = value.upper().replace(".", " ").replace(",", " ").replace("  ", " ").strip()
  return mystr

newFunction = F.udf(testFunction, StringType())

df2 = df.withColumn("myNewCol", newFunction(df.address + " " + df.city))
df2.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PySpark you cannot concatenate StringType columns together using `+`. It will return `null` which breaks your udf. You can use `concat` instead.

```
df2 = df.withColumn("myNewCol", newFunction(F.concat(df.address, F.lit(" "), df.city)))
```

Comment: +1. Thank you for explaining a reason for a cause of the issue. I was thinking of [python example](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp). But, as you explained, it's different in `pyspark`'s StringType columns.